# how could a class inherit from another class after create as instance

Tags: python

I am wondering if I can able to inherit one of class after the instance has been initialized. As following I have two class as *Child* and 'Outfit' and after create a instance as *child*. I would like it to be inherited from class *Outfit* so I can use the function get_cloth to return blue. For some reason, I do not want Child to inherit from Outfit class

```
class Outfit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cloth = 'blue' if self.gender == 'M' else 'red'

    def get_cloth(self):
        return self.cloth

class Child:
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

child = Child('tom', 'M')
print(child.get_cloth())
```

Comment: You want to turn your child into an outfit? You're seriously misunderstanding what inheritance means. (At least, I sure hope you are...)

Comment: Why don't you inherit Child from Outfit in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the previous answers, applying the concept of inheritance at the instance level rather than the class level does not make much sense. If what you really want is just for `child` to have access to the `get_cloth` method of `Outfit`, you can assign it explicitly:

```
child = Child('tom', 'M')
child.get_cloth = Outfit().get_cloth
print(child.get_cloth())
```

Note that I use `Outfit().get_cloth` and not `Outfit.get_cloth` to extract `get_cloth` as a method on not just as a function.

The fact that this is easily possible comes down to the design choice of the Python language of having `self` be an argument to every method, instead of some fixed non-local variable.

Comment: This is true, but not really all that useful. Because that `Outfit` instance isn't accessible to `child`, or to anyone else (except by digging it out of the bound method), you don't get anything more out of this than you'd get by just storing the result of that `get_cloth()` on a default, never-touched `Outfit` instance (e.g., `child.get_cloth = lambda: Outfit().get_cloth()`).

Comment: @abarnert What do you mean by *that `Outfit` instance isn't accessible to `child`*?

Comment: Well, how would you access that `Outfit` instance from inside a method of `child`, or from a caller with access to `child`? In this toy example, of course, it doesn't matter, but then in this toy example the class is pointless in the first place. Imagine there was a method `Outfit.dye(self, color)`. Neither `child` nor anyone using `child` has anything to call `dye` on, right?

Comment: Who is to say that `Outfit` and `Child` are not both defined in the same module, or can't be imported into a common module?

Comment: Being defined in the same model has nothing to do with it. What instance of `outfit` are you going to forward `dye` on, and how is that going to affect future calls to your `get_cloth` method?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to do what you're trying to do. Objects don't inherit, only types do. The instance `child` has a type that can inherit (be a subtype of) another type, but that type is `Child`, and you said that you don't want `Child` to inherit from `Outfit`.

This isn't something that necessarily has to be true for any object-oriented programming language; rather, it's the fundamental difference between class-based OO (Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, C++, Java, etc.) and prototype-based OO (JavaScript, Self, IO, and a few other languages you've never heard of).

There are some things you can do that are somewhat close to what you're asking for, but they're all things you very rarely want to do.

---

If you're interested in *subtyping*—that is, making `isinstance(child, Outfit)` true:

- You can change `Child` to inherit from `Outfit` after it's been created (e.g., by setting its `__mro__` attribute). You can even after the `child` instance has been created. Then `child` will now be an instance of something that subtypes `Outfit`.
- You can change the type of `child` to a *different* type after creation (by setting its `__class__` attribute). But you'd still need to create some type that is a subtype of `Outfit`. Maybe a type that's a copy of the `Child` class but with different bases, or maybe it's an empty class whose bases are `Child` and `Outfit`.
- You can make `Child` into a "virtual subclass" of `Outfit` by defining an `Outfit.__subclasscheck__` method. This will work even after `Outfit`, `Child`, and `child` have all been created. In this case, although `isinstance(child, Outfit)` will pass, it's not actually going to act like an `Outfit`; you're just fooling `isinstance`. Or, put a different way, you're getting nominal subtyping without behavioral subtyping.
- You can make `child` into a "virtual instance" of `Outfit`, without making `Child` into a virtual subclass, by defining an `Outfit.__instancecheck__` method.
- You can build a `Prototype` metaclass that effectively flattens out the distinction between classes and instances for its types, and instead gives you something like the Self or JavaScript object model. This is a lot of work, and your `Prototype` classes will do weird things when interacting with "normal" classes, but it is doable. Having done that, you can then modify `child`'s prototype chain however you want.

---

If you're only interested in *inheriting behavior*—not just duck typing as an `Outfit`, but letting `Outfit` do the work for you—the easiest way to do that is to forget about types and just compose an `Outfit` instance into `child` and forward. But unfortunately, that's not as easy as it sounds:

- You can define a `__getattr__`. But that won't actually be called for `child.spam`, only for `getattr(child, 'spam')`; only the type's `__getattr__` makes a difference for normal member access. If that matters (and it almost certainly does) you need to build a new type and reassign `__class__`, as described earlier.
- You can iterate all of the methods of `Outfit`, or of the composed `outfit` instance, and explicitly add forwarding (bound) methods to `child`. But only a small subset of special methods will look at the instance instead of the class. So, while `child.spam()` will work, `child + 2` will not. If that's a problem (and it usually is, but not quite as universally as the last case), you still need to build a new type and reassign `__class__`.

---

Anyway, all of these things are possible, because they are very occasionally useful, but none of them are made easy for you, because they are almost always the wrong thing to do. (If you do decide you want to do any of them, and it isn't obvious how to do it from the docs, and there isn't another question here that explains how, create a new question, explaining clearly which one you want to do and why.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a bit more safely by making Child intentionally pass on unknown attributes:

```
class Outfit(object):
    def __init__(self, child_self):
        self.cloth = 'blue' if child_self.gender == 'M' else 'red'

    def get_cloth(self):
        return self.cloth

class Child:
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.super_self = None
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.super_self is None:
            raise AttributeError(name)
        else:
            return getattr(self.super_self , name)

child = Child(...)

child.super_self = Outfit(child)
print(child.get_cloth())  # Should work now
```

Comment: This is a great quick&dirty way to get about halfway to a prototype chain. I don't think you can get the rest of the way without a metaclass and/or a custom `super` function, but I'd have to think that through (or, better, I'd love to be proven wrong…). And of course sometimes getting about halfway is all you want. (In the rare cases when you want anything like this in the first place…)